# VBA code doesn't run on pasted / inserted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a small VBA Code that I run by clicking on a button on my worksheet after selecting a cell. I tested the code typing some test values into random cells and it seemed to be working fine. But when I want to use it on my "real" data (data that I pasted into the macro-enabled worksheet from another worksheet), nothing happens. I wonder if it is because I didn't literally "type in" the data, but there just must be a way to get the code to be run on all cells! However, I couldn't find any useful answer on the Web.

Could someone help understand why my code doesn't get triggered when the pasted cells are selected?

Many thanks!

Here is my Code:

```
Sub SelectCaseTest()

Dim feldname As String
Dim metadata As String
Dim itemid As String

feldname = ActiveCell.Value
metadata = ActiveCell(1, 2).Value
itemid = ActiveCell(1, 3).Value

Select Case feldname

    Case "ACTOR"
        ActiveCell(1, 1).Value = "dc:contributor"
        ActiveCell(1, 0).Value = 6
    Case "CONTENT_TYPE"
        ActiveCell(1, 4) = "(8,'dc:type','" + metadata + "',48," + itemid + ",NULL,1),"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I edited my post with the code.

Comment: Put a break point on the Select Case statement and check if feldname is an exact match to one of your Cases. Watch out for trailing spaces and upper case versus lower case letters

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks bug-free so I am assuming that your SELECT CASE isn't finding a match to the cell contents.

To debug, put a break-point at `Select Case` and check if `feldname` matches any of your cases manually. Or try:

```
MsgBox ("|" + feldname + "|")
```

or print to the Immediate Window (View > Immediate Window):

```
Debug.Print ("|" + feldname + "|")
```

Watch out for trailing spaces, and upper-case versus lower-case letters.

Depending on what type of data your pasting into the cells, you might try replacing `.Value` with `.Text`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! You are right: the function isn't recognizing the cell values in my data table as corresponding to the cases... But I have no idea why, as a can see no difference between the value that works and the one that doesn't. I definitely think this has to do with copying / pasting the data, so I'm just gonna start again with the original file. In any case, many thanks for your help! :-)